Write the Boolean Function F(A,B,C,D) using no more than 2 Nor Gates
I am working on a problem where I have to draw a logic circuit using no more than 2 Nor gates. The function F(A, B, C, D) = Σ(2,4,10,12,14) with don't care conditions Σ(0,1,5,8). After drawing the k-map and working through the functions, I am ready to say that it can't be done.



ab\cd
00
01
11
10




00
x
x
0
1


01
1
x
0
0


11
1
0
0
1


10
x
0
0
1



C'D' + ACD' + A'B'CD'
D'(C'+AC+A'CB')
D'(C'(A+A')+AC+A'B'C)
D'(AC'+AC+A'C'+A'B'C)
D'(A+A'C'+A'B'C)
D'(A+A'(C'+B'C)

ChatGPT is telling me that C'+B'C is 1, so the entire function boils down to D', which I know isn't true. If I try to choose the largest possible groups from the kmap, I get C'D'+ ACD' + A'B'D', which comes down to D'(C'+B'+A)
I also know that 2 nor gates can handle a maximum of 3 inputs. Am I right in saying there is no solution?

ChatGPT is telling me that C'+B'C is 1 it's not, rather it's (BC)' a.k.a. B'+C'.

Thanks. I thought it was wrong, but ChatGPT would not expand it's answer.

From the Karnaugh map:
F = B'D' + C'D' + AD'

This can be rewritten:
F = (B' + C' + A) D'

Finally:
F = ((B' + C' + A)' + D)'

Disregarding the inverted inputs, this is a circuit with two NOR gates.

The logic checks out, but I thought NOR gate problems like this were only allowed 2 inputs?

@TheIncrediblyStupidOne: I'm not used to working all the way down at the gate level, but it is my understanding that you can feed two inputs into a NOR gate, say, and then feed the output from that along with a third input into a second NOR gate, and so on.

Triple-input NOR gate actually exist in practice. An example is the 74HC27.
